# How can I get email id of the google user while using playgameservices sdk in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-plus, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-plus-signin

I am using playgameservices sdk for unity in my game. However, I am not able to get the email id of logged in user on iOS. Do I need to define any permission while initialising the playgamesserviceplatform class? Please let me know the correct procedure to get email id.

Thanks

Comment: There currently is a bug in the Google Play Game Services for iOS SDK preventing getting the the email address.

Answer (score 3):

I found this [link](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#retrieving-players-email-or-access-token) that might be helpful. Below is the process described in the link

> In order to access the player's email or access token, you need to configure a web app associated with your game in the Play Game Console. If your game does not use a custom back-end application, you can set the launch URL to be https://localhost.
>
> Copy the client id from the web application and enter it in the setup dialog for this plugin. This will configure the correct permissions and settings needed to access the email address and access token.
>
> To get the email:
>
> ```
>    Debug.Log("Local user's email is " +
>     ((PlayGamesLocalUser)Social.localUser).Email);
> ```
>
> To get the access token:
>
> ```
>    Debug.Log("AccessToken is " +
>     ((PlayGamesLocalUser)Social.localUser).accessToken);
> ```
>
> To get the id token:
>
> ```
>    Debug.Log("IdToken is " +
>     ((PlayGamesLocalUser)Social.localUser).idToken);
> ```
>
> NOTE: The email and access tokens are only available on the UI Thread. If you need to get these from the non-UI thread, you can use the helper function RunOnGameThread:
>
> ```
>    GooglePlayGames.OurUtils.PlayGamesHelperObject.RunOnGameThread(
>     () => { Debug.Log("Local user's email is " +
>                 ((PlayGamesLocalUser)Social.localUser).Email);
>             // use the email as needed
>           });
> ```